# Codeigniter access forbidden to image folder at project root

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, permissions, routes

I'd like to put my images/assets in folders at the same level as my application directory, but every I try to link to an image, I get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access (my base url)images/myimage.jpg on this server
```

This how I'm trying to access the image in my view:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/myimage.jpg">
```

Is this an issue with my routes.php? I haven't really touched it, nor have I created a .htaccess file.

If the issue is that I haven't told it how to handle the base_url + some_asset_folder, where and how do I go about configuring that? I only know how to tell the routes to use a particular controller class and method, not to access a particular directory.

I'm new to PHP frameworks and a new to CodeIgniter – any help is much appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: What are the folder permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your .htaccess file that might be causing problems .
Allow your file types in .htaccess .

Comment: Yep, it was my .htaccess file. Nixed the "Deny from all" and added "Options FollowSymLinks". Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to keep your images, stylesheets, javascript, uploads etc. files are separate from the application. Create a folder `assets` in the root folder that contains `application`  and `systems`.

So it'll contain the folders `application, assets, system etc.`
Add folders inside `assets` -- `images, css, js, uploads etc.`

and you can access it using

`<img src='<?= base_url() ?>assets/images/image.jpg' />`

This would probably be the best way to do it. This is what I've been doing for my applications, so for me this is the best way. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this, my "application" and "systems" folders are on the same level as my "images" folder, but when I try to access my images it's giving me the "Forbidden" message. Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: @anniebabannie I'm assuming you're using your localhost. Are you using WAMP server or any other? If so, is your web application folder inside the `www` folder? like `www/mywebapp` and then inside the `mywebapp` folder you have the codeigniter files, the `application, system, .gitignore, index.php, images etc.`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you have CI installed outside of your public http web folder, you will not be able to access your images directory through a browser due to server permissions. One way around this would be to create a controller to fetch and serve the image file.